# unity 2D (look at) object disappears

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, transform

I have a moving object that I want to look at the target it's moving towards, here is my code:

```
void Update ()
{
    transform.LookAt( target.transform.position);
}
```

The problem is the object does look at the target while moving, but it disappears from the screen, but it's there at the same :/

Edit: Since the game is in 2D view, the object kinda turns sideways, so when I was talking about it disappearing but still there, what is really happening is that it turns and faces the object it's looking at. I hope that makes things more clearer.

Comment: What do you mean it it disappears? What disappears and is still there? Are you sure the moving object is still in the field of view of the camera? Maybe the camera slowly enters inside the object / is on the same position as your object and hence cannot see it

Comment: Check my edit in op.

Comment: hmm.. does it turn 90 degrees or 180? Is your object a 2D plane?

Comment: 90 degrees, and yes it's a 2d sprite.

Comment: I usually work with 3D .. but I suppose if you are turning a 2D object 90 degrees with respect to the camera, you cannot see it.. It doesn't have a thickness - which is what you should see if you turn it 90 degrees... try turning it to 0 / 180 and check if the camera sees it.

Answer (score 0):

Check the sorting layer order of your 2d object. If it has an order less than the order of any other object then it will disappear behind it. 
You can check it in detail from this link. 
https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/2d/sorting-layers

Comment: can you post screenshots of the game?

Comment: I just realized the problem you are facing 
correct me if I'm wrong but you want the object to look left or right according to the target right?

Comment: Yes. exactly, doesn't that involve changing it's x scale?

Comment: yes set the scale to -1 if you want to change the direction of the object. 
Change the x scale between 1 and -1